# Django: Request timeout for long-running script

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pythonanywhere, django-1.9

I have a webpage made in Django that feeds data from a form to a script that takes quite a long time to run (1-5 minutes) and then returns a detailview with the results of that scripts.
I have problem with getting a request timeout. Is there a way to increase time length before a timeout so that the script can finish?

[I have a spinner to let users know that the page is loading].

Comment: You can refer this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459738/django-long-request-timeout/51129849#51129849

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't change the request timeout for individual users on PythonAnywhere. In the vast majority of cases, a request that takes 5 min (or even, really, 1 min) indicates that something is very wrong with the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the timeout value can be adjusted in the web server configuration.

Does anyone else but you use this page?  If so, you'll have to educate them to be patient and not click the Stop or Reload buttons on their browser.

Comment: Thanks! Is that the WSGI configuration file?