# Django long request timeout

Tags: python, django

I have a view in a Django application that take as input a large CSV file. It cycle all the rows and insert datas on DB.
Locally I have no problem but when I deploy my proj online the view give me back a timeout after some time.
My webserver configuration is Nginx + Gunicorn.
I tried to increase timeout on Gunicorn and `proxy_connect_timeout`, `proxy_read_timeout` on Nginx by writing a large number (120000) and now it's better, I get timeout after about 90 seconds instead of 30 (default for Gunicorn) but still is not what I expected and it's not enough to finish my job.
Also I don't like so much this approach. I don't want infinite timeout for every request.
What's the best approach to deal with long request and not have timeout?
Maybe by answering to user with a message and then run the job in background? Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: For jobs like that, you should use task queue such as celery+rabbitMQ.

Comment: Don't try to increase timeout. A view should respond quickly when it is invoked. If you need to perform a long running task, you should look around asynchronous job execution. Celery is best for this, but you can also run your job in a different thread using python threading. See https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html

Comment: Yes you're right, increasing timeout is not the solution that's why I asked..thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Celery With Django for Background Task Processing that means process the CSV file with celery async task.

OR

As a quick hack, if you don't want to use celery; use multi-threading to process the CSV and save the result of the processing in DB or file and server the result from DB or file.

Note: Never Process big files on main thread; always try to use a different server to process the big files.If different server is not possible then try to process it in background task

[Many solutions can be found on this StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602761/django-background-task)

Comment: I thought to use Celery but, as it's just a backend option for admin and maybe it's not used so much, I prefer to don't add Celery and RabbitMQ/Redis to my stack so I was searching if there is an easier solution...what about the second part of your answer? I didn't get it, could you explain it better please?

Comment: I used Celery with Redis and I solved my problems, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
    I spend more time to increase the request timeout. And Finally I got the soluton
    For **Django Rest API ( Nginx + supervisor + Gunicorn + AWS )**

     1. Add timeout in the gunicorn(Supervisor config)

        [program:gunicorn]
         command = <env_path>/env/bin/gunicorn --pythonpath=<python_path> --name=<nginx_name> --bind unix:/tmp/myproject.sock --workers 3 --graceful-timeout=900 --timeout=900 <project_path>.wsgi:application
        directory=<project_path>
        autostart=true
        autorestart=true
        stopsignal=TERM
        stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn.stdout.log
        stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
        stdout_logfile_backups=5
        stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn.stderr.log
        stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
        stderr_logfile_backups=5

     2. Add proxy on nginx file

     proxy_connect_timeout       900;
     proxy_send_timeout          900;
     proxy_read_timeout          900;
     send_timeout                900;

     3. Changes in Load Balancer ( If you configure  -> in EC2 instance)
 [Load Balancer][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSUrK.png
```

Comment: You can find Load Balancer screeshot here for reference
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSUrK.png

Comment: This is what helped me ! Thank you! The problem was i needed to add  "--graceful-timeout=900 --timeout=900" to my gunicorn file and provided proxy settings to nginx. Now it doesnt timeout when loading alot of data.